# Replace with previous alphabet in a given string

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in need of an Oracle-SQL query.

I have a string `$F$` and here is a situation where i have to replace this with the previous alphabet.

**Expected output:** `$E$`

This string can contain any alphabet from `A-Z`. Alphabet `A` will not be available so if it is `$Z$` then the output should be `$Y$`

Any help?

Comment: What is the expected output if the input is `$A$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CHR` and `ASCII`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '\$([B-Z])\$',
         '$'
         ||CHR(ASCII(REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'\$([B-Z])\$',1,1,NULL,1))-1)
         ||'$'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'BCDEF$Z$GHI' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | BCDEF$Z$GHI | BCDEF$Y$GHI |

---

If you just have 3-character strings in your table then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       '$' || CHR(ASCII(SUBSTR(value,2,1))-1) || '$' AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '$Z$' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | $Z$ | $Y$ |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=290e894a12d0af92d8dbe26db9771aa0)*